# Why C/C++ the structure type can be redefined in different files, but the variable and function gives an error?

Tags: c++, c

test1.cpp:

```
struct ListNode
{
    int       m_nValue;
    ListNode* m_pNext;
};
```

test2.cpp:

```
 struct ListNode
 {
     int       m_nValue;
     ListNode* m_pNext;
 };
```

ps: test1.cpp and test2.cpp are same project, run is ok.

but,
test1.cpp:

```
int a;
```

test2.cpp:

```
int a;
```

Will be redefined，error.

```
struct ListNode
{
    int       m_nValue;
    ListNode* m_pNext;
};
```

if just declaration, not definition, why

test.cpp:

```
 struct ListNode
  {
       int       m_nValue;
       ListNode* m_pNext;
  };
 struct ListNode
  {
       int       m_nValue;
       ListNode* m_pNext;
  };
```

is redefined?

and what's the difference about

```
struct ListNode;
struct ListNode;
struct ListNode{};
```

Are they all just declaration?

Comment: Please [edit] and add [mcve], including *complete* error messages. Also since you are using cpp files, you are likely using C++. If so, then remove the C tag.

Comment: @user694733 C and C++ use pretty much the same model here (there *may* be some wrinkles I am not aware of).  He is not asking for debugging help, but an understanding of how both C and C++ work.  I don't think we need a MCVE for this, anyone who can say "ODR" understands what is going on here.  C and C++ are t

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks, I know  "ODR" ,but still not very understanding of this issue.

Comment: @MartinBonner A difference arises if we consider equally named functions with differing signature: C refuses, C++ produces overloads...

Comment: @FredHu Very last paragraph: `struct ListNode;` is a declaration only. As soon as you add braces, you get a definition - in this very last example of an empty struct without any members (fine in C++, illegal in C, though).

Answer (score 7):

Basically because structures are really just compile-time things, the structure definitions themselves are not passed on to the linker.

Global and static variables on the other hand needs to be passed on to the linker which checks that there's only a single definition of everything (it enforces the [*one definition rule*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule)).

Be careful with the structures though, even if you can define a structure in multiple [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), the definitions have to be an exact character by character match. If they are not then you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Hmmm.... well, the layout may not be passed to the linker, but the *names* are, if I'm not mistaken. Perhaps focus on the difference between a *name* and an *object* (which is the difference between `extern int a;` for the name and `int a;`  for the object).

Comment: Two equally named, but different structs used in two different files for two different purposes is not a problem per se (as you said: compile time thing, who would check?); the problem comes into play only if the differing structs are used to exchange data between those two translation units...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider No, the names of structs are not passed to the linker (except as they are embedded in the names of functions with name mangling, and some hidden global tables for vtables).

Comment: @Aconcagua No.  That is wrong.  Two equally named but different structs are *undefined behaviour*.  Your C++ implementation is allowed to do anything it likes (and that includes "appearing to work").

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The name of the structure is not needed by the linker (it could be saved as part of debug information though), and the members will be translated into offsets by the compiler so they're not needed either (with the same debug-info caveat).

Comment: Might be worth saying that if a struct is used in two translation units it *must* be defined in both:  the usual way of doing this safely  is to put the definition in a header file and then #including it into both TUs.

Comment: @Aconcagua Martin is correct, it's even mentioned in the ODR-link I provided. Purely practically though, if the structures are not shared between TU's, it will most likely work fine though, It's still not correct.

Comment: @MartinBonner Well, it's made known to the linker as soon as I use objects defined elsewhere or make my own externally visible. The bare struct definition is pretty useless and is not having any impact on the generated code at all.

Comment: @Aconcagua Today's development environments can peek across TUs for optimization at link time via annotated object files. Integrated environments may even do that with the source code (respecting as-if). That opens a perhaps unexpected backdoor of information flow. Something around that idea is  probably the reason for the unqualified generality of the ODR.

Answer (score 2):

Defining `struct ListNode` multiple times is equivalent to put the definition into a header file and include it across your project. This is fine, because the same user defined type can be defined as many times as you want.

`int a;`, however, creates an instance. And non-`const`, non-`static` symbols have external linkage by default, which means that the linker will complain upon encountering two identical global symbols `a`. You can control the linkage, with defining one of the integers (in test1.cpp and/or test2.cpp) as

```
static int a; // internal linkage, not visible across files
```

or by initializing it right away together with a `const` qualifier

```
const int a = 42; // again, internal linkage
```

Comment: This is wrong `struct ListNode { int a; };` is a definition not a declaration too.